Is it possible to create a pseudo field in a block type entity?
I implement the hook_entity_extra_field_info() and it doesn't seem to go through the hook in the block type edit form admin/structure/block/block-content/manage/community/display
I created a custom module, added this hook and added a trace with Kint that is only visible in the editing forms of the node type entities.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
